# How to expand/resolve whole Excel formula path

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here's the example spreadsheet

[image]

And its formulas

[image]

Is there a way to extract the whole "expanded" formula that led to the result in A3? In this example it would be A1+(A1*2)+50 instead of A1+A2+50. Basically a single formula that only has "input" cells  (unexpandable any further, ones that do not reference other cells) in it.

Comment: Means you want to determine the steps or want to get single formula in A3 (how to get 70) !!

Comment: @RajeshS I want to have all the steps in a single formula that has only input cells in it (so A1 in this example)

Comment: Then what is wrong with your formula ,,, both shows the steps to get 70 !!

Comment: @RajeshS yes, both work. this is just an example - I want to rework/rewrite an existing spreadsheet that has multiple parts of the equation in many different cells and put it all together. For example from my actual spreadsheet D46=D49*100/B50-100, now D49 has its own equation referencing still other equations, same as B50. I know I could put all together manually but thought there might be a better way.

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic "formula reduction" tool; it would probably be a tedious thing to create.

This is because an Excel formula often is intricately dependent on other formulas - which must be one of the cornerstones of spreadsheets.
Already a large but very basic spreadsheet may contain dependency complexity beyond what you might expect at first glance.

There is some "help" though;

google for "excel formula debugging" and you will find things to try:
e.g. https://trumpexcel.com/excel-formula-debugging/ tells to enter edit mode (hit F2 on a cell) and either just hit F9 immediately, or first select an interesting portion of the present formula before hitting F9.

The other tip on that same page is using the Evaluate formula Step by Step in the "Formula" tab.

To sum it up: To eliminate the intermediate calculations (present in cells a formula depends on) might simply not be possible **without first thoroughly analyzing, and then reworking/rewriting** the spreadsheet.

Your example is very simple in comparison to how it can be in a live spreadsheet.

Comment: thanks, forgetting the "formula reduction", is there a way to pull/merge the formulas of all precedents in one go? So "A1+(A1*2)+50" in the example. At least that would make rewriting a bit faster, compared to manually finding each related cell and putting it all together.

Comment: Sorry, none that I'm aware of.